# Importing from JSON string to the database with a php page or email

Tags: java, database, json, export

I have a shopping cart.
I would like to send a JSON string which is generated after the user's payment.
I have this file .js :

```
var ProcessOrder = {

// Called when order is successful via PayPal
success : function(order, transactionId){
    $.info('Payment Success.  TransactionID: ' + transactionId);
    $.info('Order Data = ' + JSON.stringify(order));
    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title       : config.PAYMENT_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.TITLE,
        message     : config.PAYMENT_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.MESSAGE
    }).show();
},

// Called when order was cancelled by user during PayPal flow
cancelled : function(order){
    $.info('Payment Canceled');
},

// Called if an error occurs during PayPal transaction
failed : function(order, errorCode, errorMessage){
    $.info('Payment Error');
    $.info('errorCode: ' + errorCode);
    $.info('errorMessage: ' + errorMessage);
    alert(errorMessage);
}
};
```

The string that is generated after the order is this:

```
$.info('Payment Success.  TransactionID: ' + transactionId);
$.info('Order Data = ' + JSON.stringify(order));
```

and contains the details of your order.

I want to send it by email or somewhere so that I may know what to send?
Thanks in advance.

This code:

```
 $.info('Payment Success. TransactionID: ' + transactionId); 
 $.info('Order Data = ' + JSON.stringify(order));
```

generates JSON two strings:

```
 [INFO] Payment Success. TransactionID: AP-1YH922698A186825K   
 [INFO] Order Data = [{"itemID":"003","name":"Product","itemCount":1,"itemPrice":"2.50","totalPrice":2.5,"options":""}]
```

I want to save this data in a database or send email.

Comment: Can't understand your question. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Forgive my bad English.
This code: 
    $.info('Payment Success.  TransactionID: ' + transactionId);
    $.info('Order Data = ' + JSON.stringify(order)); 

generates JSON two strings:

[INFO] Payment Success.  TransactionID: AP-1YH922698A186825K

[INFO] Order Data = [{"itemID":"003","name":"Product Large","itemCount":1,"itemPrice":"2.50","totalPrice":2.5,"options":""}]
I want to save this data in a database or send email.

Answer (score 0):

Post transactionId and order JSON to PHP and parse JSON (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the server-side. Or you might as well Parse JSON on client-side and post properties you are interested in to the php page. Once you extract data from the JSON, you can save it to database or send mail etc..

Comment: How can I do this?
I do not understand anything about php and Json.
Please can you help me with code?
Thank you.

Comment: see if http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php helps @EgidioNuzzoEGi

Comment: can't do that.. i have a hectic full-time job